# Print only valid Alphanumeric Strings

Tags: java, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

**Print only valid Alphanumeric Strings**

For example, the geral print is:

```
   Xô3†kÐ€?ë±3!æq¥b.    
   Parabéns, conseguiu. 
   ñoÛD¦Ó¶Y˜…Û¬œ«÷ôQÂ.  
   Ãý™448($vúiP±ÔÅã.    
   ÝÆû4sÊìÏiÁLy[r¥…X°.
```

But i need print only this line:

```
   Parabéns, conseguiu.
```

I try this `regex` in if operator, but don't work.

```
   ^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]).*$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to escape the period with a double backslash as a period on it's own is a wildcard for "any character" as well as allow for one or more a-zA-Z... etc with the +

```
^([a-zA-Zà-úÀ-Ú0-9]+)\\.*$
```

Not sure if this will work for your implementation.  I don't know how those lines are coming in to your regex to begin with.